# "There are no fields in dtype int64." why am i getting it?

Tags: python

```
b= np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6]])
b[1,1]
```

output:----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-320f1bda41d3> in <module>()
      9  """
     10 # let's say we want to access the digit 5 in 2nd row.
---> 11 b[1,1]
     12 # here the the 1st one is representing the row no. 1 but you may ask the question if the 5 is in the 2nd row then why did we passed the argument saying the row that wwe want to access is 1.
     13 # well the answer is pretty simple:- the thing is here we are providing the index number that is assigned by the python it has nothing to do with the normal sequencing that starts from 1 rather we use python sequencing that starts from 0,1,2,3....

KeyError: 'There are no fields in dtype int64.'
```

Comment: [That code doesn't produce that error.](https://ideone.com/hVTaAz) You've left out something crucial. Post a [mcve].

Comment: The code as shown just gives the result ``3``; it does not result in a ``KeyError``. Rather, one would have to index the array's dtype as in ``b.dtype[1,1]`` to get this error.